# Deploy compiled Unit Test project to be referenced for other libraries

Tags: c#, unit-testing, deployment

As software team manager i use unit test, among many other reasons, to keep safe the code integrity, right now i need my programmer can run test but can see the unit test code

So i think if i can compiled into a assembly and refer to it in the target project then it can be use it but not see it.

Did any one have an idea about it?

Comment: Any c# code is absolutely trivial to decompile. So no matter what form you deploy the code using standard means, it is very easy to 'see it'. What is the goal you are trying to achieve? Why should the programmers `not be able to see` the code they are running?

Comment: I have no problem if anybody see the test code i just want to avoid changes on the test.

Comment: how are developers supposed to write more tests? Neveretheless, if this was some kind of a requirement to have a set of never changing tests (which, btw, will stop compiling) i would set up the repo with main repo as git submodule that would be a readonly for everyone else. (assuming you're using git)

Comment: How could a unit test project itself be "secret" whereas the code that's being unit tested, not be so?  This doesn't seem to make much sense, or I'm missing something.  Tests know about the code being tested, code being tested doesn't know about tests.

Comment: secret is not the term, i just need avoid anyone change the unit test instead of fix the code that is been tested by this unit test, in some opportunities developer has change the unit test so its code "satisfy" the requirement and its fraud that why i need to keep some unit test inmutable

Comment: but with enough change to a unit, a test might actually need updating :|

Comment: but this was my decision as manager and no for the developer who have its own set of test. I just want to guaranty that some test are inmutable without negate the option to run other test of course. like have some test read-only